# Write a large file to disk from RAM

Tags: c++, windows-7, file-io

If I need to write a large file from allocated memory to disk, what is the most efficient way to do it?

Currently I use something along the lines of:

```
char* data = static_cast<char*>(operator new(0xF00000000)); // 60 GB 

// Do something to fill `data` with data

std::ofstream("output.raw", std::ios::binary).
   write(data, 0xF00000000);
```

But I am not sure if the most straightforward way is also the most efficient, taking into account various buffering mechanisms and alike.

I am using Windows 7 64-bit and Visual Studio 2012 RC compiler with 64-bit target.

Comment: What is your target operating system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Windows, you should use [`CreateFile` API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Have a good read of that page and any links from it mentioning optimization.  There are some flags you pass in to turn off buffering.  I did this in the past when I was collecting video at about 800MB per second, and having to write off small parts of it as fast as possible to a RAID array.

Now, for the flags - I think it's primarily these:

- `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING`
- `FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH`

For reading, you may want to use `FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN`, although I think this has no effect if buffering is turned off.

Have a look at the [Caching Behaviour section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#caching_behavior)

There's a couple of things you need to do.  Firstly, you should always write amounts of data that are a multiple of the sector size.  This is (or at least was) 512 bytes almost universally, but you may want to consider up to 2048 in future.

Secondly, your memory has to be aligned to that sector size too.  You can either use `_aligned_malloc()` or just allocate more buffer than you need and align manually.

There may be other memory optimization concerns, and you may want to limit individual write operations to a memory page size.  I never went into that depth.  I was still able to write data at speeds very close to the disk's limit.  It was significantly faster than using stdio calls.

If you need to do this in the background, you can use overlapped I/O, but to be honest I never understood it.  I made a background worker thread dedicated to writing out video buffer and controlled it externally.

Answer (score 1):

The most promising thing that comes to mind is memory mapping the output file.  Depending on how the data gets filled, you may even be able to have your existing program write directly to the disk via the pointer, and not need a separate write step at the end.  That trusts the OS to efficiently page the file, which it may be having to do with the heap memory anyway... could potentially avoid a disk-to-disk copy.

I'm not sure how to do it in Windows specifically, but you can probably notify the OS of your intended memory access pattern to increase performance further.

(boost::asio has portable support for memory mapped files)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `std::ofstream` you should make sure of the following:

1. No buffer is used by the file stream. The way to do this to call `out.setbuf(0, 0)`.
2. Make sure that the `std::locale` used by stream doesn't do any character conversion, i.e., `std::use_facet<std::codecvt<char, char> >(loc).always_noconv()` yields `true`. The `"C"` locale does this.

With this, I would expect that `std::ofstream` is as fast as any other approach writing a large buffer. I would also expect it to be slower than using memory mapped I/O because memory mapped I/O should avoid paging sections of the memory when reading them just to write their content.

Answer (score 1):

Open a file with `CreateFile`, use `SetEndOfFile` to preallocate the space for the file (to avoid too much fragmentation as you write), then call `WriteFile` with 2 MB sized buffers (this size works the best in most scenarios) in a loop until you write the entire file out.

`FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` may help in some situations and may make the situation worse in others, so no real need to use it, because normally Windows file system write cache is doing its work well.